# Split multiple columns to cells using vba

Tags: excel, vba

[enter code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ph6Lr.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6ONp.jpg)

[my data in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEDBk.jpg)

I am having trouble to split multiple columns to cells. I can perform this in for one column data as per the code below. Can anyone please show me how to do this for multiple column for this file (11 column).

My code is shown here:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Get_Data_From_File()

Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook
Dim sp As String
Dim myarray() As String
Dim i, a As Integer
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim lastclm As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*")


If FileToOpen <> False Then
    Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
    OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A:A").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(1)).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    OpenBook.Close False

End If
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

For a = 1 To lastrow
sp = ActiveSheet.Cells(a, 1).Value
myarray = Split(sp, "-")
For i = 0 To UBound(myarray)
ActiveSheet.Cells(a, i + 1).Value = myarray(i)

Next
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want the extra split columns to appear to the right, or below your current data?

Comment: I want it in the right side. My code will do for the 1st column. I need this for all the columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you want.

Here is code that

- splits each column in each row
- creates a new row consisting of each split item, **replacing** the original.

*If you want the original **interleaved** with the results, that is pretty simple to do by altering how the results array is constructed.*

- The code assumes the data is on your Excel worksheet in a format similar to what you show in your screenshots.
- In the code, the splitted rows are written on an different worksheet
- You can change the relevant factors to overwrite the original, if you prefer
- The data is read into a VBA array for faster processing
- As each column is split, the splitted information is added to a collection
- After we finish processing each row, the collection object is added to a dictionary.
- When done, each row is written into a results array
- The results array is written back to a worksheet.

Note that working in a VBA array is generally much faster than working on the worksheet

```
Option Explicit
Sub multiColumnSplit()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim rwCol As Collection, D As Object
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, K As Long, V As Variant, W As Variant
    Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long
    Dim S() As String
    Dim charCount As Long
    
'read data into array
Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet1")
With wsSrc
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
End With

'will create Collection object for each row and store in dictionary by row number
Set D = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    Set rwCol = New Collection
    For J = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 2)
        S = Split(vSrc(I, J), "-")
        For Each V In S
            rwCol.Add V
        Next V
    Next J
    D.Add Key:=I, Item:=rwCol
    Erase S
Next I

'create results array
K = 0
'how many columns
For Each V In D
    K = IIf(K > D(V).Count, K, D(V).Count)
Next V

ReDim vRes(1 To D.Count, 1 To K)

'fill results array
charCount = 0
I = 0
For Each V In D
    I = I + 1
    J = 0
    For Each W In D(V)
        J = J + 1
        vRes(I, J) = W
        
            'count characters to set column width
            K = Len(vRes(I, J))
            charCount = IIf(charCount > K, charCount, K)
            
    Next W
Next V

'Set results worksheet and range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error Resume Next
    Set wsRes = Worksheets("sheet2")
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 9
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
            ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet2"
            Set wsRes = Worksheets("sheet2")
        Case Is <> 0
            MsgBox "Error No: " & Err.Number & vbLf & Err.Description
            Stop
    End Select
On Error GoTo 0
Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(vRes, 1), UBound(vRes, 2))

'write the results
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .NumberFormat = "@"
    .Value = vRes
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = charCount + 1
End With
    
End Sub
```

**Original Data**

[image]

**Results**

[image]

Comment: it works much faster. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that will do it. There will be blank spaces if one string had more dashes than another. It also assumes the maximum number of dashes is 16 (15+1)

I might make a PQ solution as well if I have more time later today.

```
Sub split()

Dim myarray() As String
Dim sp As String
Dim a, b, c, d, i, lastrow, lastcolumn As Long
Dim myrange As Range


lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells.End(xlDown).Row
lastcolumn = ActiveSheet.Cells.End(xlToRight).Column
d = 1
b = 1

Do While b <= lastcolumn
        For c = 1 To 15
            Cells(1, d + 1).EntireColumn.Columns.Insert
        Next
    For a = 1 To lastrow
        sp = ActiveSheet.Cells(a, d).Value
        myarray = VBA.split(sp, "-")
            For i = 0 To UBound(myarray)
                ActiveSheet.Cells(a, i + d).Value = myarray(i)
            Next
   Next
   d = d + 15 + 1
   b = b + 1
Loop

Set myrange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    For a = myrange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
        If Application.CountA(Columns(a).EntireColumn) = 0 Then
            Columns(a).Delete
        End If
    Next a
End Sub
```

Comment: @ Hooded 0ne. Thank you very much. it works faster.